# failed to load cache key: pull access denied powershell

Tags: docker, npm

When running docker file this line failed
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get install -y gnupg2 && wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - && apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to load cache key: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

Answer (score 19):

I just had the issue, and in my case, the problem was with multistage build: I forgot to include `as <stage_name>` in my first stage in Dockerfile.

So as the first line I had

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim@latest
```

But I should have

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim@latest as build
```

instead, since I was referencing `build` in the next stage.

Comment: Had a similar issue just now, but it was where I had named a previous stage `builder`, but was referring to it as `build` later on. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. In my case, was named image out of format.

It is wrong:

```
FROM debian:latest as imageBaseFromAnyThing
...
FROM imageBaseFromAnyThing as imageBaseFromAnyThingApp
...
```

or this

```
FROM debian:latest as image-base-from-any-thing
...
FROM image-base-from-any-thing as image-base-from-any-thing-app
...
```

Try keep simple, like:

```
FROM debian:latest as image
...
FROM image as app
```